# Accessing a ID from templateURL in angular directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have my directive which brings in a drop down of school

```
function campuses(){
    return{
        restrict: "AE",
        scope:{
            display: "@",
            optGroup: "@",
            orderBy: "@",
            showGrades: "@",
            dirClass: "@",
            campusCls: "@",
            gradeCls: "@"
        },
        transclude: true,
        templateUrl: "XXXX/XXXXX/campus-dropdown/campus-template.html",
        controller: campusCtrl,
        link: campusLink
    }
}
```

The HTML File that is being loaded in by the template URL

```
<div class="form-group {{campusCls}}">
<select
id="campus-dropdown" 
class="form-control" 
ng-model="campusModel" 
ng-options="item.campusNum as item.campusLabel {{customGroupBy}} for item in campusList {{customOrderBy}} track by item.campusNum"
title="{{display}} campuses">
    <option value="">Select all Campuses</option>
</select>
```

The main problem I'm having is getting the ID campus drop down into my directive. 
Everytime I try document.getelementbyid or $('#campus-dropdown') im only getting back null values

I've try accessing this variable in the controller and in my link but still not luck

Comment: How about a quick plunker or js fiddle that shows the problem and then we can try to solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating an isolate scope in you directive with this:

```
scope:{ display: "@", optGroup: "@", ...}
```

Working [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/w2DRiGn9kujZKpDUYCs9?p=preview)

You need to create/use a custom attribute named something other than scope.

In you controller:

```
$scope.foo = {
        display: "",
        optGroup: "",
        orderBy: "",
        showGrades: "",
        dirClass: "",
        campusCls: "",
        gradeCls: ""
    }
```

Html:

```
<campus-dir foo="{{foo}}"></campus-dir>
```

Directive:

```
foo: "@"
```